# web page keep content after refresh server side

Tags: html

I would like to create a simple text web page that keeps the content.  I want to keep the content saved on the server by what ever means (php or sql is fine).

sessionStorage and localStorage isn't what i'm looking for.   Those keep the data on the users computer and doesn't allow other computers to see the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have tried..

Answer (score 0):

So im kind of confused by your question I assume you mean pull string from mysql and display it on the webpage so here is an example.

```
    <?php
//Connect
$user = 'example';
$password = 'example';
$host = 'example';
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db('example_db');

$handle = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Example_db');
$row = mysql_fetch_row($handle);

$text = $row[0]; // Retrieve text in database
//Variable name above can be what ever you want it to be.
?>
//Example html
<h1><?php echo $text;></h1>
```

pard me if i'm wrong if so just tell me and I can see if I can further help you.